# SSIS Precedence Constraint Max Count variable inside Error handling

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

SSIS Error handling onTaskFailed event > this gets triggered multiple times however i want to trigger once only and got to be max(variable).
Currently use variable and gets incremented every time event gets triggered but i want it to trigger some sql when max count. How do i check Max(varCount) ?

Comment: What do you mean by Max(varCount)? If varCount gets incremented every time onTaskFailed is triggered, what value should it be when an sql is triggered? You can use precedence constraints (the arrows between tasks) between a variable check task and Execute SQL Task and set the Execute SQL task to only run when needed

Comment: So lets say varCount increments by 5 times and i want my execute sql task to be run on the fifth time rather than running every single time. Make sense?